# GSON deserialization error with proguard

Tags: android

I have a simple class with a list like below:

```
public class Foo {
   @Expose
    private ClassA classa;

    @Expose
    private List<ClassB> list;
}
```

Serializing and deserializing work fine. However, when I obfuscate my code with ProGurad
I get the following exception:

> com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The Json Deserializer
>   com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@406f6508
>   failed to deserialized json object [{...}, {...}, ...] given the type
>   class java.util.List

Comment: Can you post your ProGuard cfg file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add these lines to your proguard so that gson class is kept while signing your app..

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature


# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to at this lines to configure proguard correctly with GSON

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

As you can see in this example: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

Comment: Yeah, the Gson sample is great but its missing the `-keepattributes *Annotation*` so be sure to add that if you are using Gson annotations.